# Using Filter in DB vis

Tags: dbvisualizer

A very 'beginner level' doubt but i couldnt find a similiar answer anywhere so i thought lets ask the experts. How do I copy and paste multiple values for comparison in the 'filter' section for a table in DB vis. [Take this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhNOL.png)

As you can see i need to copy multiple 'rpt_per_id' and use them in the filter section. How do i do that, so that their indentation is good. I know pretty awkward question to ask but still, im not sure how to do this and this would save me some time.

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking. You need to click the Add button to insert the column in the filter area. Please re-phrase your question in case my answer don't help.

Comment: Hi @roger, I was just looking for how to reduce my work. ex. when i put these many rep_per_id values in filter, i would have to manually add a separator (a comma) after each value. Any shortcut that would help me to reduce this work?